Angular Material - MatButton vs MatButtonModule
Been refactoring my code recently and noticed that Angular Material Button example uses MatButton instead of MatButtonModule these days.
Now it makes sense considering moving towards standalone components.
Question I have is does this apply to all Angular Material components, or a limited subset of components?
I've been looking for documentation on this but cannot find it.

Aren't the *Module classes for loading in app.moudle.ts, and the non-Module classes  for the actual component instances?

@RickyMo *Module is the "traditional" angular way, pre-standalone. However I've not seen anything in Angular Material documentation indiciating when to use one over the other. In fact when you look at their examples they sometimes  use *Module sometimes without, but no clear reason why.

I can't find any specific docs on material.angular.io or Angular Material GitHub.
But I think the key takeaways are as follows:

Using standalone helps reduce the need to import an entire module and just use what's necessary.

We can assume the key components are standalone and can be imported directly without any dependency on the module.

If the component is dependent on some service that gives you null injector error, we can solve this using importProvidersFrom(<<module name>>) in the root of the application, on bootstrapApplication (if Angular Material actually needs it.


We can solve most of the problems using these steps.
Angular has already done a great job on why you need standalone.

Standalone components provide a simplified way to build Angular applications. Standalone components, directives, and pipes aim to streamline the authoring experience by reducing the need for NgModules. Existing applications can optionally and incrementally adopt the new standalone style without any breaking changes.

Basically, to use a single feature in a shared module, you had to import an entire module. This can get messy since modules do not allow the same import twice in an application. Hence to solve this complexity, the Angular team favors standalone, which is its own island with its own imports, just import it and it is ready to use. Great use cases are: Comment component which is used throughout the application. If it's standalone, the complexity of using it is greatly reduced, compared to modular, where you have to make sure it's not imported twice in the same module (should have a singular location).

Agree with approach, but was hoping to find some solid explanation of one vs other usage. As mentioned in my comment you can see in the angular material examples they use both.
Also if you run the migration for standalone components it doesn't pick up angular material content. REf https://angular.dev/reference/migrations/standalone

@Aeseir Angular material is not part of default angular package, so the migration might not support it!

@Aeseir updated with my understanding of standalone! hope it helps!

im familiar with standalone v module, lets not focus on that. Question is about Angular Material where examples they use *Module and others *Component.
Please have a look at example of MatButton (migrated from MatButtonModule) vs MatSelect (which still uses MatSelectModule). Are all components standalone ready or is it subset etc.
